# Sequence seen on the street

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

I was walking on the street when I saw the following numbers:

> $0, 7, 2, 3, 9$

The sequence continued a bit further then looped back. However, it was not the sequence I was expecting, so it took me a moment to figure out what was going on.

**Where were these numbers? And what was going on?**

Comment: You are on an infinite length street and someone wrote on lamp posts the decimals of [$\frac{\pi}{17}$](https://oeis.org/A019684) but for some reason you are running around in circles

Comment: @Marius I have never expected anything else than the decimals of π/17 any time I walked around in circles on infinite length streets. Have you?

Comment: Nope. that's why I think this is a trivial question and I wrote my answer as a comment.

Comment: I like @marius because as he said me while ago, he cant be serious too long. His comments always make me laugh. Also, I see its from oeis.org

Comment: Hm, I have a suspicion that the answer to this might be related to the answer to my as-yet unsolved puzzle at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43293/a-strange-sight-in-london. I see a pattern that fits, but am loath to reveal it as it would give away the solution to mine. Does the solution to my puzzle look like it might be similar to the solution to yours?

Comment: @paolo My answer doesn't help me solve your puzzle at all, so it might not be it.

Comment: @paolo Correction: given the top answer and your comments to it, there's definitively something. But I don't think it's the same object/context at all.

Comment: **OP**, where were the numbers? floor? wall? post? irrelevant?

Comment: @lois6b That's what the puzzle asks! Although, to be fair, the question may be a bit vague so: the numbers are on _something_ (whose functionality is provided by said numbers). That _something_ may be on a wall, a post or somewhere else (but probably not on the floor).

Comment: @OxTaz: Ah, I suspected the answer might be something like this. This is in fact very close to the answer to my puzzle, and a big hint to solving it!

Comment: @paolo Well, just spent an hour on it without success :). Sure, you can make $7, 6, 5$ look like $7, 8, 9$ if the top-right segment is stuck on, but in that case, the transportation would be irrelevant... Maybe some part is hidden from your point of view (eg. by the encasing), but I can't find a configuration that consistently gives numbers. I'll keep trying!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was on a

> seven-segment display counting upwards (eg a clock), but the top segment was stuck on, so 1 is the same as 7, and 4 looks similar to a 9 (even though the bottom segment would normally be on as well in a 9).

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: ohhh nice one. :D